# Working with a column that has a list of dictionaries

Tags: pandas

I have some data that looks like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['John', 'Amy'],
    'messy': [[{'time': 3, 'action': 'eat'}, {'time': 5, 'action': 'sleep'}],
              [{'time': 1, 'action': 'bike'}, {'time': 9, 'action': 'eat'}]]
    })

     id                                              messy
0  John  [{u'action': u'eat', u'time': 3}, {u'action': ...
1   Amy  [{u'action': u'bike', u'time': 1}, {u'action':...
```

How can I get to a dataframe that looks like this?

```
  id    time    action
John       3       eat
John       5     sleep
 Amy       1      bike
 Amy       9       eat
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative way is to first set `id` to index and then use `groupby-apply` framework.

```
result = df.set_index('id', append=True).groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda g: pd.DataFrame(g['messy'].values[0])).reset_index(level='id').reset_index(drop=True)

result

     id action  time
0  John    eat     3
1  John  sleep     5
2   Amy   bike     1
3   Amy    eat     9
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d = []
for dex, row in df.iterrows():
    myid = row['id']

    for item in row['messy']:
        item['id']=myid    # expanding the dictionaries with the correct key/value.
        d.append(item)

pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The result should look like this:

```
  action id    time
0 eat    John  3
1 sleep  John  5
2 bike   Amy   1
3 eat    Amy   9
```